# Interaction with vote buttons on tag synonyms page break tooltips

Tags: bug, tag-synonyms, localization, tooltips

I just tried to vote on [suggested tag synonyms page on ruSO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?tab=Newest&filter=Suggested) and got very weird tooltips as a result (looks like some kind of encoding issue):

> [image: ruSO tag synonyms]

Before voting or after the page reloads all tooltips look fine.

Comment: Also when I use mobile device and Responsiveness mode is on Vote buttons (thumbs up/down) are not visible [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSM4I.jpg)

Comment: @АндрейNOP this can be reproducible even on desktop by reducing the browser window width.

Comment: @АндрейNOP I created a [BR](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/388217/there-are-no-voting-buttons-on-suggested-synonyms-page-for-narrow-screen?noredirect=1&lq=1) based on your comment.

Comment: You have the right!