# Incorrect encoding while removing access for applications

Tags: bug, status-review, localization, encoding, se-applications

On international sites there's an encoding issue when removing the access from authorized applications:

[esSO](https://es.stackoverflow.com/)

> [image]

[jaSO](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/)

> [image]

[ruSO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/)

> [image]

The original English wording is:

> [image]

Comment: Related issues with encoding of translated strings: [Encoding issue for error message when editing is not possible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376378/335251), [Translated success popup-message for synonym deletion shows as HTML entities](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389079/335251)

Comment: @V2Blast more issues from my side: [one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301176/339911), [two](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/362896/339911).

Comment: @V2Blast and the [new one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389140/339911)