# There are no voting buttons on suggested synonyms page for narrow screen

Tags: bug, design, tag-synonyms, responsive-design

This issue is created based on the [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362896/interaction-with-vote-buttons-on-tag-synonyms-page-break-tooltips#comment1211005_362896) from related post: [Interaction with vote buttons on tag synonyms page break tooltips](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/362896/339911)

Responsiveness doesn't work well for [suggested synonyms page](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?tab=Newest&filter=Suggested), i.e. voting buttons (entire voting column) are hidden on narrow screen. See gif below to clarify:

> [image: No voting buttons]